# JSON object from HTTP response there but undefiend

Tags: json, node.js, post, request

In Node.js, I use request to post as such:

First I make the options

```
var ops = {
       'user':'johnny',
       'password':'password'
   };
```

Then I make the request as such:

```
 request.post({url: endpoint, formData: ops}, function(err, res, body){
           console.log(res.body);
        });
```

This then returns the data I want from an API:

```
{"user":"johnny","time":"2016-11-03T15:58:34.444Z"}
```

But then when I change the request to:

```
request.post({url: endpoint, formData: ops}, function(err, res, body){
               console.log(res.body.user);
            });
```

I get back "undefined".

Why can I access the res.body but not then then res.body.user when user is clearly an attribute of the object?

Thanks

Comment: can you log console.log(res.body.user) and console.log(res.body) at the same time and post the response

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof res.body);` give you?

Comment: it's because your response is a string. Convert it to `JSON`

Comment: Thanks, yes it was because it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your response being a string, this will do the trick :

```
var data = JSON.parse(res.body);
console.log(data.user);
```